# Programmatic Menu not showing content

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and Primefaces 5 to create a small application.

At first I followed a tutorial to just show up an Editor and a header line on the page, what worked quite well.
Then I moved on to the primefaces showcases and followed the code for the programmatic menu. (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml)

I added two menu items and 2 submenus like this:

```
@Controller(value="navigation")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class NavigationComponent {

private MenuModel model;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    //Home submenu
    DefaultSubMenu homeSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Home");
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("Home");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
    homeSubmenu.addElement(item);
    model.addElement(homeSubmenu);

    //Second submenu
    DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Second");
    item = new DefaultMenuItem("Show it");
    item.setUrl("www.google.com");
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-flag");
    secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
    model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
}

public MenuModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(MenuModel model){
    this.model = model;
}
}
```

And in the index.xhtml by adding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>
<h:form>
    <p:menu model="#{navigation.model}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

For the sake of simplicity I removed now the Editor example here. The editor is working perfectly. But the navigation bar isn't showing up any content. There is just an empty silver "box" on the page.

Hope someone can help me?

Best Regards!

Comment: Is the init() method being executed? 
Also you can try adding a growl or message component to display any potential errors.

Comment: The init() method is executed, I had an System.out.println("Something"); in there which was showing up in the logs. What do you mean with "growl" or "message" component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved the issue now by adding the following to the configuration.

First I missed the following beans:

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(
            new ConfigureListener());
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
    return resolver;
}
```

Second, under src/main/resources/META-INF I had to add the file faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javae/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.2">
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Hope it will help someone else.

Best Regards